# Algorithm for determining a Y-axis max for a polar chart

Tags: c#, math, highcharts, polar-coordinates

I've got a .Net Core 3.1 razor pages app that uses Highcharts JS to render a polar chart. I'm trying to improve a method to take the trajectory and distance from center to a point (point A), along with the trajectory and distance from that point to another point (point B), and calculates the Y-axis max needed to display all three (CENTER, A, B) on a polar chart. Current method just combines the distances. How can this be made to reduce Y-Axis on the chart when possible? I think there might be a way to use trig and the trajectories, but I haven't figured out what to do.

Ex. 1: Point A is 50 m away @ 0 deg. Point B is 50 m from A @ 30 deg. Two distances combined is 100 m. The chart shows all three points.

Ex 2: Point A is 50 m away @ 180 deg. Point B is 100 m from A @ 0 deg. Two distances combined is 150 m, and the chart is "zoomed out." The Y-Axis could be scale down to 60 m and still show all points.

```
internal void GetChartOptions(double offsetDistance, double PredictionDistance, out double yAxisMax, out double yAxisInterval)
{
        yAxisMax = offsetDistance + PredictionDistance;
        yAxisInterval = yAxisMax <= 20 ? 5 : yAxisMax <= 40 ? 10 : yAxisMax <= 80 ? 20 : yAxisMax <= 120 ? 30 : 25;            
}
```

As an analogy, think of a radar showing an aircraft. The aircraft fires a projectile, that can go in any direction. The radar should show both the craft and projectile and reduce the y-Axis max to "zoom-in" but still show both.
(For the sake of this example, disregard the physics, and think of just how to render such an image.)

Comment: To be honest I don't understand this idea with calculating the trajectory. Are you able to share some images that will clarify it? Maybe just setting the`yAxis.max` same as the `series.dataMax` which is a distance from the 0 to this point will be enough? Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mdgsv03r/

Comment: The series is generated, and then an offset is applied to the series data to position it away from center on the chart rendering. I'll try to get a picture, but I have an analogy until I can build that.

Comment: The system data for the 2nd point is only referenced to the 1st point, not the center. If we re-calc the distance from center on the 2nd point, and compare those distances, the max value from that comparison should be the y-Axis max we're looking for.

Comment: I see, but for the chart, this 2nd point refers to the center, so why the distance from the center to this second point can not be a max?